# Open a network share folder in a chrome tab from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, network-security

I have following html/js code that opens a network share folder on button click.

```
<button id="demo" onclick="clicked()">Open The Network Share Folder</button>

<script>
  function clicked() {
    const url = "file://ns-van.company.net/files";
    window.open(url,'_blank');
  }
</script>
```

When I save the above code in a htm file and open it in Chrome on my local laptop. It works - network share is open in a new Chrome tab and I can see the list of files

[image]

However, if I deploy the above htm file to a server running on my local. When I click the button, nothing happens and Chrome console will show me following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file://ns-van.company.net/files
```

My question is, is there any way , I can open a network share folder in a chrome tab, from JavaScript deployed on a website. just like I did with the code above on my local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As the error message says, it is not allowed.

Comment: thanks. Do you know why it works when I run the code from my local laptop?

Comment: Because it isn’t HTTP so its already a local resource. There’s a degree of trust there.